Why do some comment replies using the @username convention fail to work?
When I reply to a comment, I try to follow the @username convention. It almost always works fine. But sometimes it doesn’t work: i.e., I have to type out the username because it fails to appear in an autocomplete popup, and then what I typed simply disappears when the pending comment is posted. I know there is an exception that affects post owners (see Why comment reply auto-completion feature (@) sometimes doesn't work?), but that’s not what’s going on here: I’m actually the post owner, I’m trying to reply in the comments under this or that answer, and whether or not the @username convention ends up working seems random.
I’ll finish by saying that I read How do comment @replies work? and couldn’t find any explanation.

Not much we can do unless you give more details. The help FAQ page you link explains many cases. Including "automatically removed" & only the 1st @ & "When editing a comment" & "not appear in the auto-complete" etc.

@philipxy I recently had this happen in https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/624325/is-the-t-in-witch-considered-a-silent-t with the usernames LPH and Jay.

That's too vague. When it happens try to document exactly what you did on exactly what posts etc etc & try to reproduce it. Then post details. PS You may have more success in a specific site meta since everybody there can use that site.

Eg you just gave a link to a question post, but neither username you gave has commented on that post or asked it, so @ & @ completion won't work for them on that question post. But if you are talking about an answer post you have not made that clear or said what you typed on what one when what comments were present, etc.

@philipxy Both usernames gave answers on that post. LPH’s was Jul 14 at 19:18 and Jay’s was Jul 15 at 6:17. You can see my reply comments to those answers. Those are the comments in which I tried to use the convention, but it didn't work. I’m not sure what an "answer post" is.

A question is posted in a question post at the top of the page & answers are posted in answer posts below. @ only works for the comments/commenters/poster of a given post. Not for anyone on the Q&A page. As I told you neither of those users commented on that question post so @ won't work for them there. As is explained the help FAQ page: "Who can be notified" & "author of the post" "Keep in mind that the question and answers are all considered independently." [bold in original].

@philipxy Thank you for the explanation. Unfortunately, I don’t think it matches the pattern of success and failure. For example, the user herisson was seemingly in the same situation as LPH and Jay: they didn’t comment on my question post, but they did make an answer post, and I replied in a comment to their answer post. And yet the convention worked fine with respect to herisson.

People can follow posts for notifications from changes & they can just return to a post. Again: @ will not work for non-author non-commenters on a post. Your last comment here is yet again unclear about exact circumstances. Please edit your post per my comments. Clarify via edits, not comments.

@philipxy Now I’m confused. What is the difference between herisson and (say) LPH when it comes to being “non-author non-commenters on a post”?

Get back to me after you reread my comments & the help FAQ page.

@philipxy OK, I’ll reread those in the morning and let you know.

My point, in the first comment, is that maybe the cases where it doesn't provide the popup can be deterministic. aka, if you left a comment directly following mine, it being the first comment on your question, would you lack the ability to @ me due to your comment obviously being a reply to mine. @76987

"What is the difference between herisson and (say) LPH" herisson voted to reopen the question. LPH only posted an answer but otherwise is not involved with doing any actions on the question post.

This question is similar to: How do comment @replies work?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This post is a question, of which you are the owner:

This post is an answer, of which LPH is the owner:

Both of them are posts. However, you are only the owner of the question, and not of the answers posted to that question by other users.
If you're commenting on LPH's answer, then everything that you read about post owners kicks in with LPH as the owner: LPH won't show up in completion for @, @LPH will be removed, etc. The same goes for all other answers with the respective users who posted them as the owner.
